# Cannot figure out formatting issue with printf and %.2f

Tags: java

I am trying get an output from this code. It will compile and return perfectly, but as soon as I add the final " calories" string at the end I will get an error message. Literally having the " calories" at the end of the output is the difference between my code running and not. I am sorry if I worded this weird this is my first time seeking help on a platform like this.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       int age;
       int weight ;
       int bpm;
       int min;
       double calories1;
       age = scnr.nextInt();
       weight = scnr.nextInt();
       bpm = scnr.nextInt();
       min = scnr.nextInt();
       
       calories1 = ( (age * 0.2757) + (weight * 0.03295) + (bpm * 1.0781) - 75.4991) * min / 8.368 ;
       System.out.printf("Calories: " + "%.2f",calories1 + " calories");

   }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors.

Comment: okay, I took it off.

Comment: @HalfokayCS Post errors as text with your question instead.

Comment: If you are using `printf`, there is no reason to string-append to a parameter, which makes it a string that can't be formatted as float. Put the `calories` inside the format string.

Comment: The parameters that you pass to `printf()` are incorrect. You meant to pass the `double calories1` as the second parameter, however, due to the string concatenation here `calories1 + " calories"`, the second parameters is changed to `String`, which cannot be represented with the specified format (`"%.2f"`). Correct would be to put the string you want to print solely as the first parameter: `System.out.printf("Calories: %.2f calories", calories1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to format double calorie1 to a string to print double upto two decimal places

```
System.out.printf("Calories: " + String.format("%.2f", calories1) + " calories");
```

Comment: No need for the extra `String.format`, the surrounding call is already a `printf`. You can just write `printf("Calories: %.f calories", calories1);`.

Comment: printf("Calories: %.f calories", calories1). This will throw error you'll have to specify the decimal places also. printf("Calories: %.2f calories", calories1) will work